# Web deploy - PublishProfile on ISS 8

Tags: asp.net, iis, azure, web-deployment

I'm working on a ASP.NET (webform) project with IIS 8 and SQL Server 2012.
I would like to find a way to configure my ISS 8 to deploy my projects like it could be done with Windows Azure (using PublishProfile).

is it possible to reach this objective ?

Does anyone could give me some advice to configure this deployment platform ?

Thanks

Comment: ISS?  Do you mean IIS?

Comment: IIS 8, I'm working also with TFS, I don't know if it could be easier to configure IIS 8 and TFS to auto build then deploy an ASP.Net project